# What problem does Dynamic NAT solve?

Tags: nat, network-core

I have been reading the below link,  and got few question.

http://www.omnisecu.com/cisco-certified-network-associate-ccna/static-nat-dynamic-nat-and-pat.php

What I understand?

Static Nat -> Just a one to one mapping between public and private IP. Only One Private IP. So,

```
   X.X.X.123:100 -> Y.Y.Y.Y:123
   X.X.X.124:100 -> Y.Y.Y.Y:123
   X.X.X.125:100 -> Y.Y.Y.Y:123
```

Dynamic NAT ->  This still makes one to one mapping, but the public address are from NAT pool.

```
   X.X.X.123:100 -> Y.Y.Y.Y:123
   X.X.X.124:100 -> Y.Y.Y.Y+1:123
   X.X.X.125:100 -> Y.Y.Y.Y+2:123
```

Question:

1) What is that we achieve with Dynamic NAT with different IP address mapping?.  I mean, i am unable to understand the sole use of Dynamic NAT over Static NAT? What is that the problem solves this Dynamic NAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static NAT uses a **single public** IP address. That's enough to establish a communication from *inside* (local network) to *outside* (internet) just like web browsing, use streaming services as Netflix, etc.

If inside the local network I have a *web server* and I want it to be public, then in the NAT router I can **open** a public port (`80 for http`) in the public IP and directed it to the IP of the local server.

Now, a communication can be established from *outside* (internet) to *inside* (web server).

If I have another web server in my local network I can't make it public using port 80 because it is in use. I'll need a **second public** IP adddress and `Dynamic NAT` to open port 80 on that second IP and redirected to the IP of the second server.